# Error: Only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC

Tags: javascript, node.js, token, web3js

When I try to send funds from a token address to another I encounter this error: only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC

My Code:

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, token_contract_address);

const data = contract.methods.transfer(to, req.body.value).encodeABI();

const rawTransaction = {
    'from': from,
    'nonce': web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from)),
    'gasPrice': web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.gasPrice),
    'gasLimit': web3.utils.toHex(21000),
    'to': token_contract_address,
    'value': 0,
    'data': data,
    'chainId': web3.utils.toHex(chainid)
};

const privateKey = new Buffer.from(req.body.PrivateKey, 'hex');
const tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
tx.sign(privateKey);

const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')), req.body.PrivateKey)
    .then(function (result) {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(result * decimals);
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => next(err));
```

Notice I have already added ChainId

Comment: I have the same issue and I think it has something to do with the nonce not being the same for ETH as it is for Tokens. But I'm still trying to figure it out. Did you have any luck?

Comment: What is the value of your `chainid`, have you initialized that somewhere else in the code?

Comment: @coderama Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent [example](https://gist.github.com/raineorshine/c8b30db96d7532e15f85fcfe72ac719c) that looks like yours and should definitely work. What I think is happening here, is that there are already some pending transactions, so that your current nonce is causing this error message. Some small steps that might solve your issue and improve your code:

- Change `value` from `0` to `0x00`, this should also be hex encoded. Or you could leave it out, because you are also sending `data`.
- Alternatively you could set
  `value` to something like `web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('123', 'wei'))`.
- Create the `nonce` with `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address, 'pending');`. This would also include pending transactions to the count so that they are not used twice.
- And what is the reason why you are adding `req.body.PrivateKey` to `sendSignedTransaction(..)`? Just adding the serialized transaction that you signed before is enough: `'0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')`.
- It is not clear what your current `chainId` is. Try running your code on another chain to see if that works.

  - Ropsten = 3
  - Rinkeby = 4
- Finally, update all your dependencies / the tools you are using. Changes in packages may sometimes cause issues like this.

You'll find another excellent example [here](https://gist.github.com/AndreiD/675027abdaa885716ce2c5af16166510).

Comment: Came here to say that `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))` should be sufficient, good catch

Comment: @AaronMeese true. But I think the OP has a problem with his nonce and pending transactions.

Comment: There's really no way to know until we know what his/her `chainId` and whatnot looks like, but possibly